# DNS Error Randomly Takes Down Site All Day

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, hosting

I need some help on why one of my sites constantly goes offline and back online all day like 30 times a day!. The downtime varies from 10 Minutes to 55 Minutes and its really affecting me. I have other sites running just fine on the same server, same Plesk, same IIS.
Here are some details:

- The Domain is registered at GoDaddy.com (in case you need me to look up something
- Server is Windows 2008 R2
- Plesk is the Control Panel 9.x
- Running IIS 7

I was told Plesk has its own DNS so the IIS one is Off so leave it off. Not sure if this is true but since all my other sites run just fine, this is probably true.

I would appreciate the help if someone can tell me what I need to fix/add/change to this domain!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain `outlooksync.com` is registered with two nameservers, `NS1.MSWINDOWSHOST.COM` and `NS2.MSWINDOWSHOST.COM`. These are also the nameservers for `mswindowshost.com`, which requires registrar glue. But no registrar glue has been provided. So this happens:

1) Client wants to find `www.outlooksync.com`.

2) It has to ask `ns1.mswindowshost.com`.

3) So it looks up the nameserver for `mswindowshost.com` and gets `ns1.mswindowshost.com`.

4) Infinite loop. Oops.

Someone has to fix the registration for `mswindowshost.com` (by adding glue or changing the nameservers) or someone has to change the nameservers for `outlooksync.com`.

**Update**: Right now, the registrar says this:

```
mswindowshost.com
Domain servers in listed order:
  NS1.MSWINDOWSHOST.COM
  NS2.MSWINDOWSHOST.COM
  NS3.MSWINDOWSHOST.COM
```

But the nameservers say this:

```
  mswindowshost.com       nameserver = ns.mswindowshost.com.
```

Comment: I miss the old days when WHOIS lookups returned the names *and* IP addresses of authoritative name servers.

Comment: I changed the IP of outlooksync.com to a different IP address.  I have let it propogate for 3 days+  and I still have constant, constant downtime for various minutes all day.  now I do want to state I did have a 100% update for 18 hours just yesterday and I thought the issue was solved.  but then it started going in and out again.  Now what else could be wrong?  Strangest thing is that the server also hosts alot of my domains(dedicated server) and they are all OK, except outlooksync.com.  thanks David...in advance...

Comment: You need to fix the actual problem. Read my answer. Nothing has been fixed, I just confirmed the problem is still exactly the same. You have a loop: `outlooksync.com` -> `ns1/ns2.mswindowshost.com` -> `mswindowshost.com` -> `ns1/ns2.mswindowshost.com`. The problem has nothing to do with the IP, it has to do with how a client's nameserver would find the IP addresses of the nameservers.

Comment: then the same settings are on www.brightslides.com  so why does that have no issues?

Comment: Actually, the problem is subtly different. The registrar thinks the nameservers for `mswindowshost.com` are `ns1.mswindowshost.com` and `ns2.mswindowshost.com` and the zone file says it's just `ns.mswindowshost.com`.

Comment: I think I got what you mean!  I added a new host name in go daddy of ns3.mswindowshost.com and attached an IP address of the server to it.  Am I correct?  I folowed directions from here: http://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/glue_records_at_godaddy   So I just made the changes...we'll check back in a few days ! :)

Comment: Actually, since its already says "ns"....maybe I should Glue the record to "ns" rather than "ns3".....your suggestion?  ( I think I could go back and make the changes.)

Comment: Just make sure the information you give the registrar matches the information in the zone your DNS server is offering. Your zone still has only `ns.mswindowshost.com` for `mswindowshost.com`. Also, your zone serial number is zero, which isn't a good thing to leave it at.

Comment: Issue Solved. Added the IP address/new "ns" entry in GoDaddy under Hosts Summary.  Then I added the newly created ns entry under NameServers.  thanks David after going crazy from it for 3 months!

Answer (score -2):

Then you need to contact your hosting provider to check what is the issue. Or you can find another hosting provider that have UPTIME Guarantee. You can check it at http://www.microsoft.com/web/Hosting/Home. Good luck

Comment: Its my own dedicated server that hosts a number of my other sites, which are all 100% uptime.  Its only this domain.